# Inline map statement React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Currently making a site where people are able to favorite articles.  I figured the best way to check to see if an article had already been favorited was to use a map statement.  However, it returns a statement for each iteration through the loop, which is obviously what I don't want.  What I want it to do is if it's in the array do one thing, if it's not in the array do another.  I want it to basically find a match in the array, and to say "You already liked this article" which my code does.  However, it then returns the else statement per item in the array.

What I am looking for is this.  Is item in the array?  If yes, disable favorite button.  If the item does not have a match in the array, then enable button.  Here is what I have so far:

```
         { this.props.isAuthenticated ? 
                <React.Fragment>
                {this.props.user.liked_articles.map(liked => {
                    if(liked.fav_title === data.title){
                        return(
                            <React.Fragment>You have already Liked this Article</React.Fragment>
                        )
                    } else {
                        return(
                            <React.Fragment>
                            <TextField 
                            name="reasons_liked"
                            placeholder="Reasons Liked"
                            className={classes.textField}
                            variant="outlined"
                            />      

                            <Button
                            type='submit'
                            >Like Article</Button>
                            </React.Fragment>
                        )
                    }
                } )}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand your question correctly, a `map` isn't what you need, as it returns an array itself. Rather, you want to use something like [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```
{this.props.user.liked_articles.some(liked => liked.fav_title === data.title)
  ? <React.Fragment>You have already Liked this Article</React.Fragment>
  : (
    <React.Fragment>
      <TextField 
        name="reasons_liked"
        placeholder="Reasons Liked"
        className={classes.textField}
        variant="outlined"
      />      
      <Button
        type='submit'
      >Like Article</Button>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

The condition returns true if `data.title` matches at least one title in the `liked_articles` array.

Comment: Didn't even know about the some function. Thank you so much Matt.  More to my knowledge base!